# C# which screen is the projector?

Tags: c#, screen, projector

My laptop is connected to a projector.
When enumerating the screens I get 2 displays which is great.
Is there a way to detect in C# which of the screens is the projector?
I need to get its dimensions...

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You can get all screens that has been connected.

```
 Screen[] aa = Screen.AllScreens;
```

And for further information and multi screen programming  check this link..
[Check this out](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6471/Multi-monitor-programming-in-C)